# Get a substring of a string made of xCharsxInts

Tags: java, string

I have a list of constants:

```
public static final String INSTANCE_PREFIX = "in";
public static final String INDICATOR_PREFIX = "i";
public static final String MODEL_PREFIX = "m";
...
```

They have variable lengths, which are put in front of a number and the result is a variable's id. For example, it could be `in30` or `i2` or `m4353`. I am trying to make the method as abstract as possible to account for `x letters x numbers`. The letters are always going to be some prefix that is inside of my `Constants.java` so I know that much, but the method won't know with which combination it's working with.

I just want the number attached to the end. For example, I want to pass in the `m4353` from above and just get back the `4353`. Whether it uses the constants file or not is not relevant, but I include them as they may be useful for some approach.

Comment: so you want to split the string into 2 parts, the prefix and the number, and you want the number back. Do you need to verify the prefix exists in the constants? If not, just use a regex to grab the number part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you don't care about the prefixes at all, so I have ignored them in this answer. If you do care about the prefixes, please scroll down to the second half of this answer:

This code uses regular expressions to extract the trailing numbers at the end of a string.

- `()` represents a capturing group (used by `m.group(1)`);
- `[0-9]+` represents a String of digits of at least 1 in length
- `$` represents the end of the string, guaranteeing the numbers are only the ones at the end.

Here is the code:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)$");

public static int extractNumber(String value) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
    if(m.find()) {
        return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    } else {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE; // error code
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/BttYgI)

---

If you want to capture the prefix, you could use `Pattern.compile("^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)$` instead.

Note that the numbers are now the second group, so they would be captured in `m.group(2)`, and the prefix would be captured in `m.group(1)`.

Comment: I actually ended up using this because keeping the prefix was beneficial. Sorry I can't change answers now, but I appreciate the response. Wait, yes I could change answers!

Answer (score 2):

Try the `String` [`replaceAll` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

For example:

```
String x = "prefix1111111";
x = x.replaceAll("\\D", "");
int justNum = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

where `"\\D"` is any non-digit character. So it deletes all non-digits in your string.

**Note, you might want to use `Long.parseLong` or `Double.parseDouble` and the associated primitive types instead if your numbers will be longer than 9 digits as Java ints can only handle values up to 2147483647**

Comment: if the prefix is being discarded, why not just ignore all chars up to the number?

Comment: Is `"\D*"` considered a pattern? I mean I know `replaceAll` asks for regex but do I need to declare that? It is considered an illegal escape sequence by eclipse.

Comment: @erp I'm having a bit of trouble with `"\D*"` right now. But yes a regex should work fine. Perhaps try `"^[0-9]"` instead. I'm currently testing.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and it says `"\D"` is acceptable but eclipse is giving errors.

Comment: @erp Solved it. You need to double escape the `D`. And you need to assign the return value of `replaceAll`. Works for me now. Answer updated.